# Take value from paragraph in repeater with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this Asp code:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repCustomers" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repCustomers_ItemDataBound">
 <p class="casualRight" runat="server" id="pCompanyValue" >
  <%# string.Format("{0:N}",((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Value"]) %>
 </p>
</asp:Repeater>

<tr>
 <td class="CellNameButton">
  <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="btnValue" Text="Value > 0" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

And this C# code:

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // Customers and popup
            var isChecked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in repCustomers.Items) {
                // Checking the item is a data item
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
                    HtmlGenericControl pVal = item.FindControl("pCompanyValuer") as HtmlGenericControl;
                    string pvall = pVal.InnerText;
                    if (pvall?.Length == 0) {
                        var chkbox = item.FindControl("chkCustomer") as CheckBox;
                        chkbox.Checked = isChecked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When I click on the button, I want to check my checkboxes only for those that have no value. I did this C# code but it doesn't work. I don't know where I'm wrong. Can anyone explain to me where I am wrong?
[Example of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jvlo.png)

Comment: You have an extra `r` at the end of your string in `item.FindControl("pCompanyValuer")`, so shouldn't it be `item.FindControl("pCompanyValue")` ?

Comment: thanks. I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is inside of that repeater? Then no need for looping.

Just do this to get the current repeater row:

```
       // demo how to get clicked row.
        Button cmdRow = sender as Button;
        RepeaterItem rRow = cmdRow.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;

        
        Debug.WriteLine("Row clicked on = " + rRow.ItemIndex);
        Debug.WriteLine("Hotel Name from repeater = " + ((TextBox) rRow.FindControl("HotelName")).Text );

     var chkbox = item.FindControl("chkCustomer") as CheckBox;
     chkbox.Checked = isChecked;
```

So, you have the button click (sender). From that you get repeater row as per above. And from that you can use find control to get any control FROM the given row.

I am going on the assumption that you left out controls you have inside of the repeater - such as the check boxes. Give the above idea a try - so, you don't need a loop to get the current row click, just use "naming container".

Comment: Although using this technique is not good for me because my button is out of the repeater. I inserted a button inside the repeater but it doesn't work. Is there another option while the button is outside the repeater?

Comment: Well, the button code I posted? Works for GridView, listview, and repeaters (naming container). Its really nice. However, for a button outside, then the issue becomes what repeater row do you want? In other words, what repeater row is selected and how is it selected? if you want them all, then yes, you have to loop. you don't have a "selected index" for a repeater. So, you might want to consider a listview, or even a detailsview, as they have BOTH a datakeys (that manages and has provisions for PK row ID, and you don't have to display nor show the PK. And listview, or details has selectedindex